# Data wont show with looping for angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show data from for looping in my js into a modal with ng-repeat inside as detail information. Here is my .js file:

```
$http.get('.....').then(function(response){
                $scope.coba = response.data;
                $scope.totalItems = $scope.coba.length;
                for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.totalItems ; i++) {
                  $scope.coba2 = JSON.parse($scope.coba[i].additionaldata_pay);
                  return i;
               };
```

But when I run it, the detail not showing anything, like this:

[image]

Here is .html modal:

```
<h4 class="modal-title">Detail </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body" ng-repeat="item2 in coba2">
                            <p>{{item2.label}}</p> <p>{{item2.value}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
```

the response of scope coba in ARC

```
"customerid": ".....",
"paydate": ".....",
"amount": ".....",
"acquirementid": ".....",
"tracking_ref": ".....",
"billerdesc": ".....",
"productdesc": ".....",
"hpno": ".....",
"email": ".....",
"rc": ".....",
"rcdesc": ".....",
"additionaldata_pay": "[{"label":".....","value":"","valuestruk":"","required":"mandatory","type":"text","typeemail":""},{"label":".....","value":"","valuestruk":"","required":"mandatory","type":"text","typeemail":""},{"label":"","value":"","valuestruk":"","required":"mandatory","type":"space","typeemail":""},{"label":"..... .....","value":"","valuestruk":"","required":"mandatory","type":"text_hf","typeemail":""},{"label":"","value":"","valuestruk":"","required":"mandatory","type":"text","typeemail":""},{"label":".....","value":".....","valuestruk":"","required":"mandatory","type":"text","typeemail":"receipt"},{"label":".....","value":"..... .....","valuestruk":"","required":"mandatory","type":"text","typeemail":"header"},{"label":".....","value":".....","valuestruk":"","required":"mandatory","type":"text","typeemail":"header"},{"label":".....","value":".....","valuestruk":"","required":"mandatory","type":"text","typeemail":"header"},{"label":".....","value":".....","valuestruk":"","required":"mandatory","type":"text","typeemail":"header"},{"label":".....","value":"1 ORANG","valuestruk":"","required":"mandatory","type":"text","typeemail":"header"},{"label":".....","value":".....","valuestruk":"","required":"mandatory","type":"text","typeemail":"header"},{"label":".....","value":".....","valuestruk":".....","required":"mandatory","type":"number","typeemail":"detail"},{"label":"","value":"","valuestruk":"","required":"mandatory","type":"space","typeemail":""},{"label":".....","value":"","valuestruk":"","required":"mandatory","type":"text_hf","typeemail":""},{"label":"","value":"","valuestruk":"","required":"mandatory","type":"space","typeemail":""},{"label":".....","value":".....","valuestruk":".....","required":"mandatory","type":"number","typeemail":"detail"},{"label":"TOTAL BAYAR","value":".....","valuestruk":".....","required":"mandatory","type":"number","typeemail":"total"},{"label":"","value":"","valuestruk":"","required":"mandatory","type":"space","typeemail":""},{"label":".....","value":"","valuestruk":"","required":"mandatory","type":"text_hf","typeemail":"footer"}]"
```

Comment: Where is item 2 ?

Comment: in scope.coba2 inside the for loop

Comment: is coba2 an array? if so are you trying to push data to it? what you mean by return i???

Comment: remove return i and it will work!

Comment: coba2 is a json string, i want to loop the json string in entire data. $scope.coba2 = JSON.parse($scope.coba[i].additionaldata_pay), this one is for parsing json string. if i change this into 0 all my detail modal only showing 1 parsed json string in index 0 . what i want is to parse all the json string data and then display it in modal. sorry for bad english

Comment: This is difficult to analyse without knowing what kind of data your GET request will output. The default output of XMLHttpRequest is [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString), but Angular will by default convert data that looks like JSON to an object. What does `console.log(response.data)` output? There is the possibility that `$scope.coba.length` yields `null`.

Comment: @SamiHult its not null, i have check it in ARC.

Comment: @AndikaRistianNugraha In that case, the other comments will probably help you out. Still make sure that what you are trying to `JSON.parse` is actually a string, not an object.

Comment: @GauravSrivastava i have remove it but it still not showing anything

Comment: @AndikaRistianNugraha What is the result of `$scope.coba`?

Comment: And let me know if you got any console error?

Comment: initialize the object `$scope.coba2 = [ ]` globally , then check  .

Comment: i have try what you said, there is no erorr in console but it still not showing the $scope.coba2 result

Comment: @AndikaRistianNugraha Can you post the `$scope.coba` values as a text instead of image?

Comment: i have change it instead image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop should be with `additionaldata_pay` not `scope.coba`. also you should check an array condition after parse your string. try this below code

```js
angular.module("mod",[]).controller("contr",["$scope", function($scope)
{
  var response={}; 

   response.data = {object1:'', additionaldata_pay:[{lable:'1',value:'1'},
            {lable:'2',value:'2'}]};         
  $scope.coba = response.data;// it should be an array
     if(!angular.isArray($scope.coba.additionaldata_pay)) 
        {
          return false;
        }
      $scope.totalItems = $scope.coba.additionaldata_pay.length;
      $scope.coba2=[];
      for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.totalItems ; i++) {
          $scope.coba2.push($scope.coba.additionaldata_pay[i]);
          };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mod" ng-controller="contr">
   <div class="modal-body" ng-repeat="item2 in coba2">
                        <p>{{item2.label}}</p> <p>{{item2.value}}</p>
                    </div>
</div>
```

### EIDT:

- response.data should be an array or if it a string then it should be support to parse an array
- Your for loop depend by an array not by object . So in my guess from your array, You should use for loop for `$scope.coba.additionaldata_pay` instead of `$scope.coba`
- And You should check with your array index|objectName to display in ng-repeate.

Comment: i have tried what you suggest but it still erorr. here is the erorr
Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: @AndikaRistianNugraha I have edited my question. kindly check it.

Comment: thanks for your edit, i'll try it. thank you so much

Comment: can you explain to me the function var response for={} is?

Comment: @AndikaRistianNugraha leave that. that's for I declared my object into that response object. just leave that line

Comment: there is no erorr but it still not showing the label and value. and i cant console.log($scope.coba2).

Answer (score 0):

If coba2 is an array of objects, try something like this,

```
        $http.get('.....').then(function(response){
            $scope.coba = response.data;
            $scope.totalItems = $scope.coba.length;
            $scope.coba2 = [];
            for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.totalItems ; i++) {
            $scope.coba2.push(JSON.parse($scope.coba[i].additionaldata_pay));
         };
```

Comment: if `response.data` is already `JSON` (as you're getting its length) you're passing JSON Something to `JSON.parse()` as angular parse it by its own

Comment: i have try what you suggest to me, but it still not showing the  scope.coba2. and when i console log . it only display [].

Comment: and get erorr like this, Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse. i think the bracket what you suggest to me is already complete. sorry for bad english

Comment: @AndikaRistianNugraha What is the result of `$scope.coba`?

Comment: the response from http get which the format is json array, and the additional data pay is json string .